# Is this a pointless check?

Tags: php, validation

is checking if the email has been filled out pointless means that I have a function that checks for `@` & `.`? Would this slow it down or is there no harm?

**Form PHP**

```
$email = $_POST['email'];       

if (empty($email)) {
    $email_error = "Your email can not be blank!";
} else if (email_filter($email) == false) {
    $email_error = "Please enter a valid email address!";
} //Add email check here! (sql query)
```

---

**Email Function**

```
function email_filter($str) {
    if (preg_match('/(?=.*[@.])/', $str)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why not use the predefined email filter? http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php The character class is also only checking for one of the characters `.` or `@`.

Comment: @chris85 You mean the HTML required in the form one?

Comment: What kind of question is that? Obviously each additional line of code _will_ "slow down" your script. And why such thing should "do harm" is a complete riddle...

Comment: @arkascha I guess I more asking if it has a massive impact?

Comment: @Ash Well you could do that or a JS check but never trust client side validation. I meant to use the linked PHP function. Your regex also doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: And what do you actually mean by "massive impact"?

Comment: It's the other way around: There is harm in ***not*** validating your user input.

Comment: @chris85 I was not aware of there being such function but there is also client side validation. Thanks

Comment: A filter filters (something like filter out all numbers).  Rather than returning true or false.  What you are trying to write is a validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to slow you down.     The extra processing time is negligible compared to all of the other processing which happens when serving a web page.

I like to rely on the language to check just in case something changes or a regular expression is buggy:

Here is a good example from w3schools

```
<?php
$email = "john.doe@example.com";

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
  echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
  echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
?>
```

Comment: Also note that if the email address is coming from a form, then you should probably also check it on the front end using javascript.   The real slow down comes from users having to return to a previous page if a server side error is caught.    It is still a good idea to check on the server side for security and to verify valid data is sent to your application or database.

Comment: It should be very quick going back a page.  The difficult thing is notifying and hand holding the user to correct their mistakes.

Comment: Yeah I have front end validation I was just wondering really if its a good idea to check on server side (is it really needed & does it have a big impact if i do it)

Comment: @Ash Yes, server side validation is/should be required, client side validation is just for user connivence.